# Screen brightness keys not working (fn + f5/f6)

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness, asus

i'm using ASUS K501U with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Gnome-shell 3.10.4,
The screen brightness works only from settings,
i tried that, but it disabled all my fn keys:

```
In the terminal:
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
Change
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
to
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
Then, save the file.
sudo update-grub
Restart computer.
```

help me, please?

Comment: In case no-one posts a fix, I'll post a workaround to bind brightness to some other keys. Please let me know when you want me to post.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/816264/25388

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu with Unity desktop environment, one can use `qdbus` to issue some of the system commands via `dbus` service, and there are two commands for increasing and decreasing brightness.

For increasing ,

```
qdbus org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power  /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepUp
```

and for decreasing

```
qdbus org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power  /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepDown
```

These commands can be bound to keyboard shortcuts for convenience. Go to <kbd>System-Settings</kbd> ->  <kbd>Keyboard</kbd>  ->  <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd>  -> <kbd>Custom Shortcuts</kbd> , click on  <kbd>+</kbd> icon to add new shortcut.

A popup will appear, and add one of the commands above. In the screenshot you can see me adding the step-down command

[image]

Once you click apply, you will see a new entry added to the list. You can click on the `Disabled` text, and it will wait for you to press the key combination you want to correspond to this command.

[image]

I've set mine to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Down</kbd> for decreasing brightness. Feel free to select your own combination.

Comment: Serg, thank you very much.
Do you know if is it a way to display percentage of changed brightness, linke changes of sound?

Comment: @BreahnaDavid  Yes , there is , but it would require putting together a small script. Another way, would  be via brightness indicator that displays percentage in top panel. Actually, I'm currently working on an indicator like that , but with a few extra features, I should bring it to completion in a week or so. Please leave me a message if you'd be interested in that